# Free heatmapping or similar?

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I have a database with around 1 million records. Each have a lat and long. I need to be able to process at maximum I would say around half a million points onto a map with some sort of weighting.

Google Maps is great but only up to 100,000 points. Is there anything else open source that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser won't be able to handle so many markes. You browser will crash or simply won't load the page. Did you ever think about how much memory would 1 million marker use? Every marker is 2 float + other data.

You need to separate your markes into groups/sections then load the section's data via ajax or  such.